Solidify Modifier Not Working Properly
I am following along with a tutorial, and I applied thickness through the Solidify modifier. My problem now is I cannot select the outer faces on my cylinder to edit in any way.
It only allows me to select one side of faces.

This is a pic from the tutorial and how it's supposed to look.


Hello and welcome to BSE. You cannot. You have to first Apply the modifier. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8AEkR3nkrI

Thank you so much!

You can't modify the topology of an object that has "solidify" until you have applied it as a modifier. Until such time Blender will see it as a 2 dimensional plane.

Or more accurately, you cannot modify the topology generated by the modifier, the original topology can be edited.

Thank you so much!

You have geometry and you have modifiers. They aren't precisely the same thing. You can edit geometry, but (while they are modifiers) you can only "edit" modifiers by changing their parameters. Thus, while your document looks like a geometry with a modifier, you can only edit the input geometry.
In order to edit geometry produced by a modifier, you have to "apply" the modifier. This replaces your geometry with the modified geometry, "losing" the modifier in the process (that is, you no longer have the ability to edit the unmodified geometry).
I didn't see a link to the tutorial, but presumably it "applied" the modifier prior to the point you've shown. (Possibly it glossed over that, assuming you already knew to do so.)
